# JQuery preloaded data in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery has the method .data() https://api.jquery.com/data/ that allows you to store Object-like data in html elements, but these don't show up as html attributes.

I wonder if there's a way to have this data pre-rendered/loaded in the html?

Preferably using Jquery only

Comment: Yes, you can add `data-test="hello"` attribute to an element and it will be available via `$(<elem-selector>).data('test');` as "hello"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alon Eitan commented, the answer is :

> you can add `data-test="hello"` attribute to an element and it will be
>   available `via $(<elem-selector>).data('test')`; as "hello"